# Dark Theme Ask Ubuntu

Tags: discussion

Same title, different theme (heheh).

After asking my question [Dark Theme for Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16081/dark-theme-for-ask-ubuntu), I realized that it is probably hard to make a new theme, and since no one else seemed interested, I was probably one of few who needed the feature.

Because of this, I've made my own userscript that injects a CSS file which overwrites certain color values on AU, turning the site dark. (Doing this, I can see how difficult it is to change everything :P).

Right now, this isn't only for Ask Ubuntu, as it works here, on SO and on SEChat. I'm hoping to be able to make it for more sites eventually, or maybe even get some others to work on it too. I'm not posting this on MetaSE yet, because it's terrifying over there ;).

Here's a screenshot of the Ask Ubuntu home page with the theme applied:

[image]

If you're interested, check out the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/zacharee/se-dark).

The project is far from complete, even on the sites currently available. If you find something, it'd be great if you could either report on GH or submit a pull request with your own fix.

---

This post is to serve as an introduction for Ask Ubuntu. I have also [posted on MetaSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284737/dark-theme-for-stack-exchange-sites), including all currently supported sites.

Comment: Can you provide installation instructions?

Comment: @edwinksl added to GH readme,

Comment: @Zacharee1 Thank you very much :) I am one of those who wanted this feature for so long and are tired of using color inverters

Comment: Try avoiding FULL BLACK and FULL WHITE

Comment: I prefer black-on-white but +1 for the effort.

Comment: This should be split into a "how do I get AU to look dark?" Q and a self-answer with the installation instructions. :) Nice job BTW.

Comment: If anyone of you who needs this, needs it for the entire web, and is using Chrome, I recommend the extension Dark Reader. It is tunable, and works infinitely better than anything else I've tried to do this. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en

Comment: @Gauthier I use that :D

Answer (score -2):

There are Extensions you can add to your browser that will allow you to have a dark theme.
As of right now, I am using Chrome with the "Hacker Vision" extension.

Comment: Those invert colors and make sites look ugly. Special formatting also breaks.

Comment: Yea... It does make it look ugly.

Comment: Not to mention the security concerns. Sorry, yes, I'm necromancing, no reply necessary. But if an extension can change page source before you see it...