# A new appearance

Tags: discussion

So basically we have Reading enhancement by using lower contrast.

We could stop using light and dark coloring appearances for GUI's. I believe this is why people gets caught-up.

I repeat Reading enhancement and yes if someone only "prefers" dark or light themes then this is an advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Exchange is not going to make a dark theme for every site, nor should they. The overhead of managing/maintaining all of those themes across one hundred something sites is *not* easy.

If you want one, make it yourself or [use a userscript](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16103/dark-theme-ask-ubuntu).

Comment: You are overgeneralizing the discussion. Of course the main team won´t do that but the desing theme if they got no-one for that then be humble instead. DOT 
Salutations

Comment: @userDepth what?

Comment: I can do plenty of themes, My proposal is not for myself. But WTV, I´ll wait for a more constructive answer.

Comment: What is a WTV? @userDepth To me this answers seems perfectly reasonable, there are so many plug ins and scripts for readability available that it is not worth SE managing the themes, it is not hard to install a browser plug in. I have to ask, how well did you think demanding a theme would go? Why not just ask nicely?

Comment: @MarkKirby I had to look up "WTV" = "Whatever". All these abbreviations designed for people texting on their phones but being typed into posts are getting tiresome.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Now I am more confused, I thought he was asking for WTV to get a dark theme :/

Comment: @MarkKirby true that!! XD flowers and bubbles!!! I tend  to do serious jokes. TY